# Fastest data structure or algorithm for fast lookup on 2 keys

Tags: c++, data-structures

In my application I'm storing a collection of data structures which hold 2 integer reference values.

- Internal reference - Represents the object in the database.
- External reference - How the object is referred to by the outside world.
  (they can't use the same value).

I am using a std::map with the internal reference as the key, but this this then leaves me with a problem that if I have to look up by the external reference, I have to potentially iterate over the whole map to find the right entry. As this list could potentially contain thousands of entries, this is painful to consider.

The following code shows a simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class MyData
{
    public:
    MyData(int internal_id, int external_id)
        : internal_id_(internal_id), external_id_(external_id) 
    {}
    int internal_id_;
    int external_id_;
    /* more data members ... */
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::map<int, MyData*> datamap;

    /*
        Build the map structure with arbitrary values.
    */
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        MyData* md = new MyData(i, (100 - i));
        std::cout << md->internal_id_ << " " << md->external_id_ << std::endl; 
        datamap.insert(std::make_pair(i, md));
    }

    /*
        Find with internal id 50 Cheap lookup O(log N) (I think)

    */
    std::map<int, MyData*>::iterator it1;
    if((it1 = datamap.find(50)) != datamap.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Found Mydata with internal id 50 external id is " << it1->second->external_id_ << std::endl;
    }

    /* 
        Find with external id 35. Expensive lookup O(N)
    */
    std::map<int, MyData*>::iterator it2;

    for(it2 = datamap.begin(); it2 != datamap.end(); ++it2)
    {
        if(it2->second->external_id_ == 35)
        {
            std::cout << "Found with external id 35 internal id is " << it2->second->internal_id_ << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    /* remove from map and clean up allocated MyData objects ... */
}
```

Which approach could I take to take to improve the look up from the external reference?

I have considered the following as options.

- 2 maps both pointing to the same thing but keyed on different values.
- A simple database (sqlite). Maybe but could be overkill.
- Maintain another map which maps the external reference to the internal reference.

Of these the 3rd option seems like the most sane. Are there any better options?

Comment: `this is painful to consider` Why are you considering instead of actually measuring?

Comment: why do you require two id's? who determines them? i.e. where did the 35 and 50 come from? a user, etc?

Comment: One refers to the object in the database (long established system not of my creation), this is how I recognise this object when receiving updates about it from the system. The other is how the client application refers to the object from an external interface.

Comment: @PaulRooney in that case 3 is probably wise, just for sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If either of the keys are near-contiguous (i.e. typically use successive values without too many unused numbers in between) then an array - directly indexed by that id - is optimal, otherwise
- if you're creating new keys that are ever-higher numerically, you could `push_back` to a `vector` and use a `std::binary_search` or even an [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search), otherwise
- `unordered_map` or `map`.

As always - to know what's fastest, implement the alternatives and measure (but I've listed them above in my expected order of performance).

If using the 1st or 3rd option, you might want to put both maps into a class so that insertions & deletions are consistently done across both, and linked-to objects only deleted when not needed (you could also manage this using shared pointers but that might be a bit heavyweight - depends on your needs.

Comment: actually, if you need to delete on internal id's you can always lookup by internal id, and get the external id from MyData.

Comment: @user3125280 good point - can't say I'd actually bothered to read the code, but it's there in `MyData` so that hangs together.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks guys I will consider these answers and upvote/accept accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It may be enough to just map external id's to internal id's. That way an object can always be found given either of its id's. If you need to delete something via one key, you find it, determine it's other key, then delete it and its external key entry.

(This so you don't have to change the existing lookup code, only add a new map)